# Getting http code 400 on Magento REST API call where token has 'admin' & 'all' privileges

Tags: magento-enterprise, api, magento-1, rest-api

I'm trying to create a customer using the **Magento REST API**.

I can use my token to retrieve/update data just fine, but for whatever reason I am unable to create an account, regardless of the permissions I set ("*All*" or "*Custom with checked boxes*").

Here is a screenshot of the Magento admin, if you notice, for whatever reason, Customers does not have a Create option and I cannot figure out why that is either, and may ultimately be why I am unable to use the POST `/api/rest/customers` call as outlined in the Magento documentation.

[image: screenshot of the Magento admin]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the **Create** permission is missing is that it's not in the **`api2.xml`** file for the **`Mage_Customers`** module. The **`_create`** method that is needed is also missing.

You can add the following to a custom module's **`api2.xml`** file to add the missing create permission.

```
<config>
    <api2>
        <resources>
            <customer>
                <privileges>
                    <admin>
                        <create>1</create>
                    </admin>
                </privileges>
            </customer>
        </resources>
    </api2>
</config>
```

You'll also need to add the missing **`_create`** method by extending the **`Mage_Customer_Model_Api2_Customer_Rest_Admin_V1`** class.

Comment: If i try to get customer list using REST API i am getting error -> screenshot -> snag.gy/3PSxvm.jpg -> URL -> 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers. and if i try to get products its working -> screenshot -> snag.gy/sePpyw.jpg -> url 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products, can i get help regard customer API error? @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Answer (score 0):

While developing a website we found that many "write" operations for REST APIs were not working very well. Our general solution was to use SOAP for writes and REST for reads, as REST is slightly faster than SOAP.